# How can I get the current widgets name of a node?

Tags: entities

I'd like to know if it is possible to get the current widgets of a node ?

field_info_widget_types() shows all the widget

But I'd like to get the widgets the current page is using and not all of them :(

Is there a way to to it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and I also find a way to display all the field used in the current node !

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){    
    $entity=$form['#entity_type'];
    $bundle=$form['#bundle'];

    $instance = field_info_instances($entity, $bundle);
        foreach ($instance as $key => $value) {
          if(!empty($value['widget'])){
            $widgetlist[$key] = $value['widget']['type'];
          }
        }
        foreach ($instance as $key => $value) {
            $fieldlist[$key] = $value['field_name'];
        }
    var_dump($widgetlist);
    var_dump($fieldlist);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of [`field_info_widget_types()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_widget_types/7) :

> Returns information about field widgets from `hook_field_widget_info()`.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `$widget_type`: (optional) A widget type name. If omitted, all widget types will be returned.

You might be leaving the parameter empty. Hence, it is returning all field widgets. Pass the name of the widget from the current node, to get the right information. You can use [`menu_get_object()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) to get the node object of the current page, and find the appropriate widget to pass to `field_info_widget_types()`.

Comment: well if I try field_info_widget_types('geofield_openlayers'); it will give only information about it regardless if it is in the current node